# Android camera2

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create simple camera application. here is source code:

```
package com.homeinc.basiccamera2.app;   
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public  void takePicture(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Uri fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUST_CODE);
    }

    private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                     Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"myPics");
        if (!imagesFolder.exists()){
            if (!imagesFolder.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("BasicCamera2","cant create dir");
            }
        }
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File image = new File(imagesFolder.getPath()+File.separator+"IMG_"+timeStamp+".jpg");
        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
        return uriSavedImage;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUST_CODE && data != null){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Toast.makeText(this, "saved: " + data.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                // canceled
                Toast.makeText(this, "saved: " + data.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                // fail
                Toast.makeText(this, "cant save: " + data.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Look at onActivityResult method it has 3 parameters, and it should receive data from Intent in data param, but it always null. Pleas tell me what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this (you can just need to define the directory and file name) should do the trick for you. There is no need to use the Intent to obtain the picture as you give the location of the file.

```
private void takePicture() {
    File newdir = new File(getImageDir());
    newdir.mkdirs();

    String file = getFileName();
    File newfile = new File(file);
    try {
        newfile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {}

    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUST_CODE);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        useFileName(getFileName());
    }
}
```